# How to use BERT in seq2seq model?

Tags: neural-network, bert, transformer, transfer-learning, sequence-to-sequence

I would like to use pretrained BERT as encoder of transformer model. The decoder has the same vocabulary as encoder and I am going to use shared embeddings. But I need `<SOS>`, `<EOS>` tokens which are not trained with BERT. How should I get them ? Can I use `<CLS>` token as `<SOS>` and `<SEP>` as `<EOS>` ? Or I have to create these two embeddings as trainable Variables and concatenate them to the decoder input / labels ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle, it is possible to reuse the special tokens as you describe.

However, according to [research](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D19-5611.pdf), you should not freeze BERT, but fine-tune the whole model with your data, in order to obtain better translation quality.

Another option would be to reuse just the embeddings instead of the whole model.